# Problem with catching the response from rest-assured request

Tags: java, html, rest, url, rest-assured

I'm using JAVA and REST-assured library to get the response from GET request. I wish to get response from this URL: `https://www.samsung.comsmartphones/` (yes, without / between .com and smartphones)
Please find my below code:

```
String URL = "https://www.samsung.comsmartphones/";
RestAssured.baseURI = URL;
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET, "/");
```

But on the last line it's just quiting from the program without any error message. 
Please, help me how can I catch a response?

Comment: That address doesn't exist. Put it in a web browser and see what response you get.

Comment: Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: Yes, I know that. This is why I need to catch response which would mean "This address does not exist"

Comment: Hi! Just try to display the `response` object and check its content.  Also, I'd advise using errors/exceptions handling. 
Check out an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp

Comment: I used the code you provided and the last line throws an `UnknownHostException`. From what you stated in your question - have you got other results?

Comment: Fenio, Thank you, it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
try{
            String URL = "https://www.samsung.comsmartphones/";
            RestAssured.baseURI = URL;
            RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
            Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET, "/");

            int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("Statuse code: "+statusCode);
            throw new UnknownHostException();
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e){
            System.out.println("Exception is: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
```